# In what order a default value for a column is added while inserting a row

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[state_record](
    [row_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [state_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [user_login] [varchar](24) NOT NULL,
    [time_entered] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [comment] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [end_time] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[state_record]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT state_end_time_constraint] CHECK  (([time_entered]<=[end_time]))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[alert_state_record] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__alert_sta__time___3E723F9C]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [time_entered]


INSERT INTO alert_state_record(row_id, state_id, user_login, comment, end_time)
values(1,1,'max','resolving', getdate())
```

Insert to this table sometimes produces error "The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "state_end_time_constraint". Is this because value for time_entered is calculated after end_time.

```
INSERT INTO alert_state_record(row_id, state_id, user_login, comment, time_entered, end_time)
values(1,1,'max','resolving', getdate(), getdate()) however works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you run this:

```
INSERT INTO alert_state_record(row_id, state_id, user_login, comment, end_time)
values(1,1,'max','resolving', getdate())
```

The `VALUES` clause(s) will be considered, and all functions evaluated, such that the actual values to be inserted are available. If the keyword `DEFAULT` is used, it will *not* be evaluated at the same time as the other evaluations take place

Only at a later point in the evaluation will the system perform a check to see whether there are default values for any columns not mentioned in the column list, or columns whose entry in the `VALUES` clause specified `DEFAULT`, and actually evaluate such default constraints to obtain values for those columns.

If you're unlucky, the two calls to `GETDATE()` (in `VALUES` and in the `DEFAULT` constraint) will obtain two different values.

This is unlike the second situation where the two calls to `GETDATE()` (in `VALUES`) are considered to be part of the same statement (I know it feels like the same ought to be sayable for the first situation, but it isn't), and you're guaranteed that both calls will receive the same value.

Comment: So I have to go with this then  INSERT INTO alert_state_record(row_id, state_id, user_login, comment, time_entered, end_time)
values(1,1,'max','resolving', getdate(), getdate())

Comment: @sanmitra - it should also be noted that the above is an implementation detail. Future versions of SQL Server could behave differently.

Comment: @Damien- Actually I am using SQL server 2008 and ibatis as abstraction layer. I am getting the issue only in case of iterative insert.Anyways tks for the help